# Sql Query Create Hourly to 5 Product Sale for day

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show report for Hourly top five product sales count from whole day

following is my query

```
Select count(*) as SALES_COUNT,
       PT.name,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM T.created) as hour 
  FROM PRODUCT_TBL P INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_TBL T on T.PID = P.ID 
 WHERE T.created <= '2018-05-22 23:50:58' 
   AND T.created >= '2018-05-22 00:00:00' 
   AND P.ID IN (Select P.PID
                  FROM PRODUCT_TBL P 
                       INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_TBL T on T.PID = P.ID 
                 WHERE T.created <= '2018-05-22 23:50:58' 
                   AND T.created >= '2018-05-22 00:00:00' 
                 GROUP BY PT.ID,
                 order by COUNT(*) desc LIMIT 5) 
 GROUP BY PT.name, 
          hour 
 ORDER BY hour asc, 
          TRANSACTION_COUNT
```

But this will generate daily top five i need hourly top five .

Sample Data

```
 Transaction_TBL
   ID PID AMOUNT     Created             Modified 
    1  1   35     2018-05-22 16:30:58 2018-05-22 16:30:58
    2  1   35     2018-05-22 16:30:60 2018-05-22 16:30:60
    3  1   35     2018-05-22 16:31:60 2018-05-22 16:31:60
    4  1   35     2018-05-22 16:40:58 2018-05-22 16:40:58
    ----------
    5  2   10     2018-05-22 16:15:58 2018-05-22 16:15:58
    6  2   10     2018-05-22 16:15:58 2018-05-22 16:15:58
    7  2   10     2018-05-22 16:15:58 2018-05-22 16:15:58
    ----------
    8  3   05     2018-05-22 16:45:58 2018-05-22 16:45:58
    ----------
    ----------
    9  5   135    2018-05-22 18:01:58 2018-05-22 18:01:58
   10  5   135    2018-05-22 18:01:58 2018-05-22 18:01:58
    ----------
    6  7   110    2018-05-22 18:45:58 2018-05-22 18:45:58
    ----------
    7  1   15     2018-05-22 18:59:58 2018-05-22 18:59:58
    ----------
    ----------
    8  4   15     2018-05-23 01:10:58 2018-05-23 01:10:58
    9  5   15     2018-05-23 12:15:58 2018-05-23 12:15:58

PRODUCT TBL
ID NAME
1  P1
2  P2
3  P3
4  P4
5  P5
6  P6
7  P7
8  P8
```

Expected output

```
Product SALES_COUNT HOUR
    P1      04        16 
    ----------
    P2      03        16
    ----------
    P3      01        16
    ----------
    P5      02        18 
    ----------
    P7     110        18
    ----------
    P1      01        18
```

How i can achieve this

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help.  "Hourly top five product sales count from whole day" does not do justice describing what you want.  I can't even figure out if the result table should have 5 rows or 120 rows, or perhaps something else.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks desired result is updated . I need hourly top five PRODUCT sales count for whole day

Comment: But this will generate daily top five i need hourly top five . - don't think so it's not valid sql. It would help if you could provide sample data (i can't be bothered to make it up myself). Grouping by hour and adding a row number might be a way to go.

Comment: @P.Salmon Sample Data added ...
Expected out will be
i need hourly aggregation on transaction count and need top five for that hour and same for remaining hour

Comment: "But this will generate daily top five i need hourly top five" That query will generate nothing since it is with syntax error in many levels.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sub Query will return daily top five PID based on this i have put date clause for external query

Comment: Please edit your query as my previous edit. See the edit revision number 7. Your formatting make the query terrible to read (besides the wrong syntax). And the subquery alone may work, but your entiry query will not. There are AND clauses without previous clauses (... where and ...) There are duplicated group by and order by in the same level

Comment: @JorgeCampos apologize for the inconvenience caused . Query now updated i have huge amount of table relation so i couldn't share original one which may create confusation same query i have created for two table